# Adjusting BRFSS weights, 2000-2010

Tags: survey-sampling, survey-weights

I'm trying to create new BRFSS weights for county-level estimates of risk factor prevalence. I believe the current weights in the dataset are used to calculate state-level prevalences and if I need a **direct** estimate prevalence of a smaller area these weights must be adjusted.

I've been trying to find some documentation on how to adjust these weights. I'm using the pre-2011 datasets where post-stratification was the primary weighting methodology (vs. raking). Here is the calculation for the weights and a link below describing the variables (page 8-10):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/upTvI.jpg

http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2000/pdf/overview_00.pdf

I don't think all the variables are in the dataset to re-calculate the weights themselves, and most CDC documentation refers to adjusting the post-stratification weight. Is the easiest way to proceed to divide by their post-stratification categories (i.e, recalculate this value for the entire dataset), and then re-calculate it for the area I'm interested in? Anyone have experience with this or any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against doing anything with the BRFSS weights. I am not sure what exactly your task is, but I am pretty sure you don't have access to all of the internal data that BRFSS statisticians do (demographics; geography; sampling rates; internal decisions such as weight trimming). I suspect that you expect to gain some precision by calibrating to the county / MSA / other sub-state geography targets, but I doubt you would gain much. The gains are conceptually asymptotic, and for a county that contributes 5 or 10 cases to the BRFSS data set, you would only blow up your design effects with no actual gain in anything.

Technically speaking, your sub-state areas are domains, and statistics for these can be obtained just as easily with `svy , subpop()` in Stata or `subset()` design object in R. No fiddling with weights ever needed.

Your highlighting of the **direct** estimates hints at the small area estimation familiarity; I believe that the (composite) SAE approach to BRFSS would work best.